# How to show In-Stock label for configurable product on products page

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, stock

i have products page for simple product and configurable product like this :

[image]

as you can see from above image, there is no **In-Stock label** for configurable product, but when i click view details there is In-Stock label, is there any way to show the **In-Stock label** in products page for configurable product?